# Multiple Hibernate Envers Revision Entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

I've got two jar-Files with entities in persistence.xml:

```
    <jar-file>/lib/model.jar</jar-file>
    <jar-file>/lib/central-model.jar</jar-file>
```

central-model.jar contains some entities which are subclasssed in model.jar.

central-model.jar is part of a CRUD-Application and needs a Revision Entity.

model.jar is also part of a CRUD-Application and also needs a Revision Entity.

The tables are located in different Schemas, linked by a Databaselink.
So there is only one Persistence Unit.

Deploying leads to the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of the same entity name twice: REVISIONEN
```

Has anybody run into such an issue?
How did you solved that?

Comment: So both model.jar and central-model.jar contain the Revision entity?

Comment: Yes, they do. Revision-Entity of model.jar points to ab table in one database schema, Revision-Entity of central-model.jar point to another database-schema.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. As @Naros assumed, I'm dealing with '@RevisionEntity'. Unfortunately, two PersistencContexts aren't possible as I subclass from central-model to model. Seem's like I have to search another solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you imply when you use the term *Revision Entity*.

Given that your question is tagged with `hibernate-envers`, I am going to assume you're referring to an entity that is annotated with `@RevisionEntity`.  If that's accurate, then what you are describing is not possible, at least not within a single persistence unit.

The only way to support having multiple `@RevisionEntity` annotated classes is to separate them into their own persistence units.

If you're not referring to the above and are describing a scenario where you have two entities with the same name but different classes, you'll need to follow [@Wabi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3021232/wabi)'s advice and give each of them a unique name to allow Hibernate to differentiate them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override entity names in both JARs to allow Hibernate to make a difference between them:

in model.jar:

```
@Entity(name="prefixA.Revision")
public class Revision {}
```

in central-model.jar:

```
@Entity(name="prefixB.Revision")
public class Revision {}
```

In queries then use:

```
createQuery("from prefixA.Revision")
```